# DisplayPort MST and HDMI adapter

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, displayport

I have a Dell u2715h monitor which has both a DisplayPorts **in** and a DisplayPort **out**. It claims to support DisplayPort 1.2 and MST (Multi-Stream Transport). I do not have a second DisplayPort enabled display to put after the u2715h in the daisy chain, but I was wondering if I could put an HDMI adapter on the Display Port output, and use that to connect to a second, regular monitor.

Theoretically this should be possible, as the MST spec says that the last device in a chain can be DisplayPort 1.1a rather than 2. And I don't see how any adapter is any different than an actual display. However, in practice, I am unable to get it to work.

Is my theoretical proposal sound?
Or any ideas on how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know every device in MST chain must support MST technology. Often chipper monitors that have only one DisplayPort in, supports that they are last in a chain, but this also must be specified.
I have also tried using DisplayPort adapter to HDMI on DisplayPort out of Dell Monitor supporting MST, but it simply does not work and I believe this is not supported by DP MST chain.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.
The catch is to use an **active** Displayport to HDMI adapter.

My Setup is:

Laptop with USB C

-> into Dell Monitor USB C In

-> from Dell Monitor Displayport Out

-> into **Active** Displayport Adapter to HDMI

-> into old HDMI only Monitor